# Creating Packet Editor proxy

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

so i am actually working on a side project that would listen to packets but i have ran into a roadblock, this might be a st*pid question or error, but i cant seem to bypass it.

In my main form, i am trying to put my server creation code inside my 'Load' Event.

In my project, i have a Server class and Client class.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Server server = new Server();
    server.RemoteAddress = "your.server.here";
    server.RemotePort = 7777;

    server.Start();
}
```

I am getting an error which states:

"The type or namespace name 'Server' could not be found." does this mean i have referenced it incorrectly ? if so, do i need to include anything ?

within my project, i have a folder created named Classes, inside that folder i have the Server.cs and Client.cs

Any help with this error would be greatly appreciated.

Software: Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 on Windows 7 (Not compatible but works)

Comment: You need to include the namespace it's under by typing `using nameSpace`. In visual studio when you create a folder it automatically makes a new namespace for you, and I tend to just change the namespace instead of using the auto-generated one. So I assume your Server.cs and Client.cs says this: `namespace YourProjectName.Classes` because it's in Classes "folder"; if so you can just erase the `.Classes` part so the namespace matches.

Comment: P.s. "proxy", "packet", "packet-sniffers" have nothing to do with your question and neither does your title. Your actual question is, "Why am I getting this error: The type or namespace name 'Server' could not be found".

Comment: Awesome, i cant try this till i'm back at home but i'll give it a shot. My namespace is called ExampleTcpProxy.Classes , if i take out .Classes it will get rid of that error ?

P.s, i just got rid of those tags, thanks :)

Comment: It will get rid of the error if the calling code is also inside of the namespace "ExampleTcpProxy", if not then erasing ".Classes" will not work. You have three options that I know of: 1) include `using ExampleTcpProxy.Classes;` at the top of your *other source file* (the one with `Form1_Load` in it), 2) *assuming* your `Form1_Load` is in the `ExampleTcpProxy` namespace then just erase ".Classes" like was suggested, or 3) change the call to `ExampleTcpProxy.Classes.Server server = new ExampleTcpProxy.Classes.Server();`. Also google "c# namespaces" for information (MSDN C# Programming Guide).

Comment: Thank you for your help, what you suggested and explained has helped and fixed my problem, i really appreciate it :)